# "expose and prosecute claims of fraud"

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs

**Is the phrase "claims of fraud" used properly here?** To me, "expose and prosecute the fraud" is correct while "expose and prosecute claims of fraud" is wrong because, claims of fraud are exactly the exposure of the fraud which should be prosecuted."  I am not very sure.

> A Donald Trump supporter who donated $2.5m to help **expose and prosecute claims of fraud** in the presidential election wants his money back after what he says are “disappointing results”.
>
> Source: The Guardian   [Trump supporter who gave $2.5m to fight election fraud wants money back](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/nov/28/trump-donor-election-fraud-sues-money-back)

Comment: The whole statement is stupid because private parties do not “prosecute” any crime in the U.S. judicial system. The Guardian of course is not a U.S. publication and simply may have used the wrong word out of ignorance. Moreover, any prosecution is formally only an attempt to prove that someone has committed a crime. A prosecution involves an alleged crime, which could reasonably be called a “claim.”

Comment: @JeffMorrow "Prosecute" _is_ used outside criminal law. In civil law, a lawyer can prosecute a case or a claim, basically meaning to pursue legal action with regard to a case/claim. As [an example, I found this](https://casetext.com/case/gonzalez-v-us-144) in a simple Google search for "prosecute a claim": "First, because Ms. Gonzalez is not the surviving spouse she cannot prosecute a claim for damages to the decedent under Florida's survivor statute, Fla. Stat. § 46.021, assuming there is a claim to prosecute."

Comment: @EddieKal Good point. You are correct that “prosecute” can mean to “proceed at law.” In the context, however, of this article and topic, what is being discussed are allegations of crimes, namely intentional and massive violations of the election laws by agents of the state, not private torts. In the context of the original question of whether it was better to say “prosecute claims of fraud” or “prosecute the fraud,” it seems to me that the everyday, criminal meaning was intended. No one not a lawyer says “I am going to prosecute X for alienation of affection.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two verbs in parallel in this verb phrase: expose and prosecute. I think there is something to your misgivings about this verb phrase, although in my opinion only one of the verbs has some semantic issues.

"Expose" has two relevant meanings:

1. to make public, e.g. *expose a crime ring*
2. to reveal the true nature of, to show a hidden bad quality/thing, e.g. *I am going to expose that website if I don't get a refund.*

Neither really fits this verb phrase. You are right that it should be "expose fraud" as opposed to "expose claims of fraud". Because if you are going to expose claims of fraud, I will take that to mean you will show those claims of fraud to be fraudulent.

However, I think the use of "prosecute" here is totally fine. "Prosecute" is used outside criminal law. In civil law, a lawyer can prosecute a case or a claim, basically meaning to pursue legal action with regard to a case/claim. As an example, I found [this](https://casetext.com/case/gonzalez-v-us-144) in a simple Google search for "prosecute a claim":

> First, because Ms. Gonzalez is not the surviving spouse she cannot prosecute a claim for damages to the decedent under Florida's survivor statute, Fla. Stat. § 46.021, assuming there is a claim to prosecute.

The relevant sense is given by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prosecute) as:

> to institute legal proceedings with reference to
> *prosecute a claim*

Comment: Please see whether my edit works:  "help expose and prosecute claims of fraud" ====>>>>"help expose the fraud and prosecute claims of it"

Comment: @NewPlanet Yes, it does, but reads clunky. "Prosecute" in this sense is legal jargon. Journalistic writing often aims to be laconic and fluid by using obscure words. I would recommend leaving it out.